# Drill down view in Tableau Dashboard

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to view the dataset by clicking on bar of the histogram. Below is the example of the histogram. I want to click on any bar of the histogram and want to visualize the dataset that is involved in making this bar. Its a kind of detailed/drill down view of the dashboard.

Is there any way to do such thing?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rishab, there are two popular solutions that might be appropriate for you.  First, you could add a tabular report of the relevant data in the same dashboard, and link the two by a dashboard action.  The quickest way to do that would be to right-click on the tab of your histogram worksheet and select "duplicate as crosstab."  Then, add this new crosstab to your dashboard.  Finally, create an action linking the two: click on your histogram and then, in the small toolbar that appears in the upper-right, click on the down-pointing triangle for "more options."  Select "use as filter."
[use as filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep7DC.png)

Alternatively, you could enable showing your crosstab, or another visualization, in your pop-up tooltip, as described here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/viz_in_tooltip.htm